# 2 column table presentaion control, like the properties window in the dev environment

Tags: vb.net, controls

in a windows form if i want to duplicate the properties window layout on my form, which is basically a 2 column table with title on the left and value on the right, what control do i use to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

A DataGridView component can be used to achieve a similar visual style and functionality, though it is not exactly the same.

To add columns, click the Smart Tag and change the settings, click "edit columns", and you know the rest.

If you want the exact same functionality as the properties window, and let your users edit the properties of an object, you can use the Properties control.